# Can any one please tell me which one is the optimized code for preventing duplicate accounts to be inserted or updated

Tags: apex, trigger, performance, duplicate-management

Which one of the following triggers are optimized for preventing duplicate accounts?

---

```
trigger AccountDuplicateTrigger on Account (before insert,before update) {

    List<Account> existingAccount = new List<Account>([Select Id, Name From Account]); 

     for(Account a : Trigger.new){
         for(Account acc:existingAccount){
          if(acc.Name==a.Name)
          a.adderror('You cannot create a dulplicate account');
         }

     }
}
```

---

```
trigger AccountDuplicateTrigger on Account (before insert,before update) {

     List<String> NameList=new List<String>();

    for(Account a:Trigger.new)
        NameList.add(a.name);

    List<Account> acc=[SELECT Name from Account where Name in NameList];

    for(Account a:trigger.new)
    {       
        if(NameList.size()>0)
            a.addError('Duplicate account cannot be inserted');
    }
}
```

Comment: The optimized solution is using the out-of-the-box **[Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&language=en_US)** feature.

Comment: A wise man told me one day: "The less there is code, the less there is code to maintain".

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't write code to implement this feature. Instead use out-of-the-box **[Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&language=en_US)**.

If you really feel compelled to use `Apex`, you're on the right track with the second approach, but it won't work. You need to get a `Set<String> existingNames`.

```
Set<String> existingNames = new Set<String>();
for (Account record : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :nameList])
    existingNames.add(record.Name);

for (Account record :  trigger.new)
    if (existingNames.contains(record.Name))
        record.addError(...);
```

Comment: It's worth noting as @sfdcfox did below, that validations should be done in the after trigger. Because you cannot guarantee the order of in which triggers fire, two 'before' triggers could fire, and the second could change the name to be a duplicate after the one that performs the validation.

Comment: Another win for **Duplicate Management** as [it fires after all `before` triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The first trigger will result in a QueryLimit once more than 50,000 accounts exist in the database. Also, a loop over the entire database will eventually result in CPU limits being reached, probably even before you reach the 50,000 row query limit.

The second format also won't work, because NameList.size() will always be greater than 0, so no new records could ever be inserted once a single record exists in the database.

The more appropriate version of this code would need to check to see if the record queried matches a record in the trigger, because otherwise you'll query the record already in the trigger.

That looks like this:

```
trigger preventDup on Account(after insert, after update) {
    Map<String, Id> nameIds = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
        if(nameIds.containsKey(record.Name)) {
            record.addError('Duplicate account not allowed.');
        } else {
            nameIds.put(record.Name, record.Id);
        }
    }
    for(Account record: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :nameIds.keySet() FOR UPDATE]) {
        if(nameIds.get(record.Name) != record.Id) {
            Trigger.newMap.get(nameIds.get(record.Name)).addError('Duplicate account not allowed.');
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I'm doing this in an 'after insert' to make sure we don't miss any records. I'm also using FOR UPDATE to make sure that we don't miss accounts inserted at (nearly) the same identical time.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, When I tried this code, it is throwing an exception: Apex trigger preventDup caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: preventDup: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: Invalid field SFDC Computing for Account: Trigger.preventDup: line 8, column 1.   Also, it is preventing any new account to be inserted(which is not duplicate)

Comment: @Shrishti Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed it.